# Finder sidebar icon for my folder

Tags: finder, icon

I want to put a folder called, say, Fonts in the Finder sidebar. Normally, putting a folder there gives you a generic folder icon (see the Fonts folder below):

[image]

However, I want to change the sidebar icon of the Finder folder to something like a stylized *f*. How would I do this?

One possible way would be to change the generic folder icon into the stylized f, but this would only really be viable if I wanted to put one folder there. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, at least without serious hacking.

OS X supports changing folder and app icons through the "get info" pane (open "get info," click the icon to select it and copy or paste). You can copy an icon from one app or folder and paste it onto another.

**However**, when I tried this with a folder on my Mac, it did not affect the icon in the sidebar. It looks like the sidebar uses the **type** of the item to choose the icon, rather than using the icon in the info.

Comment: Hey Aaron, as of today we are at macOS 10.15. Is it possible now or do you know a hack to accomplish this?